# Filling Data from MySQL not happening in Modal Form

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog

My Modal is not firing on click of the button. I have tried every possible approach that I know and attempted all possible "Hit & Try" Methods. So I reverting to this forum for help. My Codes are follows:-

Main.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic MySQL Data using Ajax & PHP</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic MySQL Data using Ajax & PHP</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="recordsfromraky" class="table table-striped table-bordered">        
        </table>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        fetchChange();
      $('.view_data').click(function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
            var fired_button = $(this).val();
            alert(fired_button);

                     $('#dataModal').modal("show");  

      });  
      function fetchChange() {
                var finyear = "2017-18";
                var cmdname = "HQ TC";
                var stnname = "All Stations";
                var statusname  = "All Status";
                var cfaname     = "All CFA";
                var wkcatname = "All Categories";

                $.ajax({  
                        url:"get_value.php",  
                        method:"POST",  
                        data:{finyear:finyear, wkcatname:wkcatname,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname, statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
                        success:function(data){  
                             $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);
                        }  
                });
            };
 });  
 </script>
```

get_value.php code is as follows:-

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/CommandWks/phpAssets/dbconnect.php';
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);    

    $finyr          = $_POST['finyear'];
    $commdname      = $_POST['cmdname'];
    $stationname    = $_POST['stnname'];
    $statustype     = $_POST['statusname'];
    $cfanamed       = $_POST['cfaname'];
    $catname        = $_POST['wkcatname'];

    $finyr          = str_replace('"', '', $finyr);
    $commdname      = str_replace('"', '', $commdname);
    $stationname    = str_replace('"', "'", $stationname);
    $statustype     = str_replace('"', "", $statustype);
    $cfanamed       = str_replace('"', '', $cfanamed);
    $catname        = str_replace('"', '', $catname);

    //var_dump($_POST);////////////////////////////////////////

    $wherefy ='';
    $wherecmd ='';
    $wherestn = '';
    $wherestatus ='';
    $wherecfa ='';
    $wherecat ='';
    $tcn='';

    if (empty($finyr)){ 
        $wherefy = ''; 
    }else{                                          
        $tcn = "'" . '%' .  str_replace(' ', '', $finyr) . '%' . "'";
        $wherefy = 'WHERE (`amwplist`.`Work_ID_by_MoD` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';
    }

    if (!empty($stationname)) {
        if ($stationname === "All Stations"){
            $wherestn='';

        }else{
            $tcn=''; 
            $tcn = "'" . str_replace("''", "", $stationname) . "'";
            $wherestn =  'AND (`stationlist`.`Station` = ' . $tcn . ')';   

        } 
    }else{          
        $wherestn='';
    }

    if (!empty($commdname)) {
        if ($commdname === "All Commands"){
            $wherecmd='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  str_replace(' ', '', $commdname) . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecmd =  'AND (`amwplist`.`Work_ID_by_MoD` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecmd='';
    }

    if (!empty($statustype)) {
        if ($statustype === "All Status"){
            $wherestatus='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $statustype . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherestatus = 'AND (`workstatuslist`.`Status_Type` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherestatus='';
    }

    if (!empty($cfanamed)) {
        if ($cfanamed === "All CFA"){
            $wherecfa='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $cfanamed . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecfa = 'AND (`cfalist`.`CFA` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecfa='';
    }

    if (!empty($catname)) {

        if ($catname === "All Categories"){
            $wherecat='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $catname . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecat = 'AND (`workscategorylist`.`Category_Type` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecat='';
    }

        $WhereCondition =  $wherefy . " " . $wherestatus . " " . $wherestn . " " . $wherecfa . " " . $wherecat . " " . $wherecmd;

        //var_dump( $WhereCondition);
        //var_dump($wherefy);
        //var_dump($wherecmd);
        //var_dump($wherestn);
        //var_dump($wherestatus);
        //var_dump($wherecfa);
        //ovar_dump($wherecat);


        $sql ="SELECT
            *
            FROM `amwplist`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `workscategorylist` ON `amwplist`.`Category_ID` = `workscategorylist`.`Category_ID`
            INNER JOIN `stationlist` ON `amwplist`.`Station_ID` = `stationlist`.`Station_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `commandhqlist` ON `stationlist`.`Command_ID` = `commandhqlist`.`CommandHQ_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `sectorlist` ON `stationlist`.`Sector_ID` = `sectorlist`.`Sector_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `celist` ON `stationlist`.`CE_ID` = `celist`.`CE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cwelist` ON `stationlist`.`CWE_ID` = `cwelist`.`CWE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `gelist` ON `stationlist`.`GE_ID` = `gelist`.`GE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `ifalist` ON `amwplist`.`IFA_ID` = `ifalist`.`IFA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cdalist` ON `stationlist`.`CDA_ID` = `cdalist`.`CDA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cfalist` ON `amwplist`.`CFA_ID` = `cfalist`.`CFA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `workstatuslist` ON `amwplist`.`Status_ID` = `workstatuslist`.`Status_ID` " .   
            $WhereCondition . " " .
            "ORDER BY substring_index(amwplist.Work_ID_by_MoD, '/', 1), CONVERT(substring_index(amwplist.Work_ID_by_MoD, '/', -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
            ";

            $tableRow  = '<thead>       
                    <tr>        
                        <th>Category Type</th>          
                        <th>Station</th>                    
                        <th>MoD ID</th>                 
                        <th>Nomenclature</th>                   
                        <th>Cost</th>                   
                        <th>Status</th>                 
                    </tr>       
                </thead>     
                    <tbody>';
            $conn = new mysqli($DBSERVER, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //var_dump($conn);
            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                //$idnumber = CONVERT(substring_index($row['Work_ID_by_MoD'], '/', -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER);
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<tr>' ;
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Category_Type'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Station'] . '</td>'; 
                $trow = $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'];
                //var_dump($trow);
                //var_dump('<td><input type="button" name= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'] . '" value= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'] . '"  id= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD']  . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>');
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td><input type="button" name= "' . $trow . '"' . 'value= "' .  $trow . '"  id= "' .  $trow  . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>'; 

                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Nomenclature'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Cost'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Status_Type'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow .  '</tr>';

            }           
            $tableRow  = $tableRow .  '</tbody>';
            //var_dump($tableRow);
    echo ($tableRow);
    $conn->close();
    ob_end_flush();

?>
```

The function .click() on clicking the MoD ID in the third column is not firing. The content of rows in this column looks like this:-

```
<input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/1" value="AMWP/2017-18/1" id="AMWP/2017-18/1" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">            
<input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/2" value="AMWP/2017-18/2" id="AMWP/2017-18/2" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">
<input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/3" value="AMWP/2017-18/3" id="AMWP/2017-18/3" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">
```

I now think that maybe there are Handle issues here because the table is being filled by get_value.php into main.php and then I am trying to fire Modal by clicking the button generated by get_value.php.

Comment: I think it's the Handle issue because of the Table getting filled by calling ajax function to fill the table on `main.php`. The Code works fine if the Table is filled Hard coded or without calling ajax function to fill the table.  There has to be a work around to fill using `get_value.php` and then add Handles for the Buttons on the `main.php` . So if anyone may please guide me with this wherein I fill the tale in `main.php` by getting data from from ajax call to `get_value.php`  and then be able to click on the buttons to open Modal.

Comment: I Feel it's something to do with where to position the ajax to call modal. Maybe its outside $(document),ready() because the page is already ready and then buttons are added. Maybe or maybe not. But please help.

Comment: on a different note: when you use POST values in MySQL queries you should really sanitize it or you are open to injections. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to bind a click event on a non existing object. i.e. `$('.view_data').click(...` happens before your ajax call is finished and therefore there are no elements that have the class `view_data`.

You have two options:

1) don't bind the event on the button, but on `body`. I personally prefer this method because it doesn't bind the event but uses a delegation. It's easier to debug and maintain (especially if you end up having a lot of events in one document):

```
$('body').on('click', '.view_data', function(){
    alert('clicked ' + $(this).val());
});
```

2) put the event binding in the success method of the ajax call AFTER you write the results to the DOM

```
  fetchChange();

  function fetchChange() {
            var finyear = "2017-18";
            var cmdname = "HQ TC";
            var stnname = "All Stations";
            var statusname  = "All Status";
            var cfaname     = "All CFA";
            var wkcatname = "All Categories";

            $.ajax({  
                    url:"get_value.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{finyear:finyear, wkcatname:wkcatname,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname, statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
                    success:function(data){  
                        $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);

                        $('.view_data').click(function(){  
                            var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
                            var fired_button = $(this).val();
                            alert(fired_button);

                            $('#dataModal').modal("show");  

                        });  
                    }  
            });
        };
```

});

Comment: Yes sir, This works. I knew it that there is something to do with the Handle here. Meanwhile I found another work around. In that, I have appended the script of .click  to the $tablerow at the end of loop before returning the table data to main.php. That too works. Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 0):

The amended get_value.php is as follows:-

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/CommandWks/phpAssets/dbconnect.php';
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
    ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);    

    $finyr          = $_POST['finyear'];
    $commdname      = $_POST['cmdname'];
    $stationname    = $_POST['stnname'];
    $statustype     = $_POST['statusname'];
    $cfanamed       = $_POST['cfaname'];
    $catname        = $_POST['wkcatname'];

    $finyr          = str_replace('"', '', $finyr);
    $commdname      = str_replace('"', '', $commdname);
    $stationname    = str_replace('"', "'", $stationname);
    $statustype     = str_replace('"', "", $statustype);
    $cfanamed       = str_replace('"', '', $cfanamed);
    $catname        = str_replace('"', '', $catname);

    //var_dump($_POST);////////////////////////////////////////

    $wherefy ='';
    $wherecmd ='';
    $wherestn = '';
    $wherestatus ='';
    $wherecfa ='';
    $wherecat ='';
    $tcn='';

    if (empty($finyr)){ 
        $wherefy = ''; 
    }else{                                          
        $tcn = "'" . '%' .  str_replace(' ', '', $finyr) . '%' . "'";
        $wherefy = 'WHERE (`amwplist`.`Work_ID_by_MoD` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';
    }

    if (!empty($stationname)) {
        if ($stationname === "All Stations"){
            $wherestn='';

        }else{
            $tcn=''; 
            $tcn = "'" . str_replace("''", "", $stationname) . "'";
            $wherestn =  'AND (`stationlist`.`Station` = ' . $tcn . ')';   

        } 
    }else{          
        $wherestn='';
    }

    if (!empty($commdname)) {
        if ($commdname === "All Commands"){
            $wherecmd='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  str_replace(' ', '', $commdname) . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecmd =  'AND (`amwplist`.`Work_ID_by_MoD` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecmd='';
    }

    if (!empty($statustype)) {
        if ($statustype === "All Status"){
            $wherestatus='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $statustype . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherestatus = 'AND (`workstatuslist`.`Status_Type` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherestatus='';
    }

    if (!empty($cfanamed)) {
        if ($cfanamed === "All CFA"){
            $wherecfa='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $cfanamed . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecfa = 'AND (`cfalist`.`CFA` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecfa='';
    }

    if (!empty($catname)) {

        if ($catname === "All Categories"){
            $wherecat='';
        }else{
            $tcn='';
            $tcn = "'" . '%'.  $catname . '%' . "'"; 
            $wherecat = 'AND (`workscategorylist`.`Category_Type` LIKE ' . $tcn . ')';   
        } 
    }else{          
        $wherecat='';
    }

        $WhereCondition =  $wherefy . " " . $wherestatus . " " . $wherestn . " " . $wherecfa . " " . $wherecat . " " . $wherecmd;

        //var_dump( $WhereCondition);
        //var_dump($wherefy);
        //var_dump($wherecmd);
        //var_dump($wherestn);
        //var_dump($wherestatus);
        //var_dump($wherecfa);
        //ovar_dump($wherecat);


        $sql ="SELECT
            *
            FROM `amwplist`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `workscategorylist` ON `amwplist`.`Category_ID` = `workscategorylist`.`Category_ID`
            INNER JOIN `stationlist` ON `amwplist`.`Station_ID` = `stationlist`.`Station_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `commandhqlist` ON `stationlist`.`Command_ID` = `commandhqlist`.`CommandHQ_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `sectorlist` ON `stationlist`.`Sector_ID` = `sectorlist`.`Sector_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `celist` ON `stationlist`.`CE_ID` = `celist`.`CE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cwelist` ON `stationlist`.`CWE_ID` = `cwelist`.`CWE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `gelist` ON `stationlist`.`GE_ID` = `gelist`.`GE_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `ifalist` ON `amwplist`.`IFA_ID` = `ifalist`.`IFA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cdalist` ON `stationlist`.`CDA_ID` = `cdalist`.`CDA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `cfalist` ON `amwplist`.`CFA_ID` = `cfalist`.`CFA_ID`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `workstatuslist` ON `amwplist`.`Status_ID` = `workstatuslist`.`Status_ID` " .   
            $WhereCondition . " " .
            "ORDER BY substring_index(amwplist.Work_ID_by_MoD, '/', 1), CONVERT(substring_index(amwplist.Work_ID_by_MoD, '/', -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
            ";

            $tableRow  = '<thead>       
                    <tr>        
                        <th>Category Type</th>          
                        <th>Station</th>                    
                        <th>MoD ID</th>                 
                        <th>Nomenclature</th>                   
                        <th>Cost</th>                   
                        <th>Status</th>                 
                    </tr>       
                </thead>     
                    <tbody>';
            $conn = new mysqli($DBSERVER, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //var_dump($conn);
            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                //$idnumber = CONVERT(substring_index($row['Work_ID_by_MoD'], '/', -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER);
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<tr>' ;
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Category_Type'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Station'] . '</td>'; 
                $trow = $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'];
                //var_dump($trow);
                //var_dump('<td><input type="button" name= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'] . '" value= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD'] . '"  id= "' .  $row['Work_ID_by_MoD']  . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>');
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td><input type="button" name= "' . $trow . '"' . 'value= "' .  $trow . '"  id= "' .  $trow  . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>'; 

                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Nomenclature'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Cost'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow . '<td>'. $row['Status_Type'] . '</td>'; 
                $tableRow  = $tableRow .  '</tr>';

            }           
            $tableRow  = $tableRow .  '</tbody>';

            $tableRow  = $tableRow .  "<script>$('.view_data'" . ").click(function(){  
                                                    var employee_id = $(this).attr('id');  
                                                    var fired_button = $(this).val();
                                                    alert(fired_button);

                                                 $('#dataModal').modal('show');  

                                                }); 
                                        </script>";
            //var_dump($tableRow);
    echo ($tableRow);
    $conn->close();
    ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Please not the appending of  at the end of the loop. That too did the trick.

Comment: that's a rather dirty solution. Keep your JS in one place (in general: avoid inline JS. Put it in a .js file). And consider using event delegation (i.e. `.on()`) instead of direct event bindings.

Comment: Yes sir, your solution is better and good. No doubt. All i intend to show is alternate method, though not a good coding practice.